# How to programmatically build the effective model of a pom file?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3, aether

I would create programmatically the effective model from a pom file to get all inherited attributes in the pom model instance. I would analyze some attributes of a pom - but I need for it all attributes - incl. inhertied.

What have I to do? I have tried Sonatype Aether but I did not find a example.

Comment: a) Why do you want it? b) You could build a maven plugin that produces a report of what you want and execute it under maven.

Comment: take a look at [jcabi-aether](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aether/), maybe will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this Gist https://gist.github.com/reiz/6203767. It shows a method which builds a MavenProject inside of a maven plugin. On the MavenProject you can call methods like project.getDependencies() and so on.

Answer (score 3):

You could just run mvn help:effective-pom to get the pom that maven is actually using, including all default inherited and parent pom inherited attributes. I don't believe this would give you all the transitive dependencies of listed dependencies, but it should give you what you are asking for here.