# How to get parent POM from child POM using java

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, parent, hierarchy

At the moment I have a Maven Model which I get with MavenXpp3Reader by reading the child pom.

```
 MavenXpp3Reader reader = new MavenXpp3Reader();
 Model model = reader.read(new FileReader("pom.xml"));
```

The model has a `model.getParent()` method which returns the Parent object having `artifactId / groupId / version`.

Can I access the parent POM using this data, or is there another way?

I need this to build a complete Parent Pom hierarchy using only JavaCode.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525318/how-do-i-obtain-a-fully-resolved-model-of-a-pom-file

Comment: First question: Why do you need to go that way ? What is the purpose of that? What kind of problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.3/maven-model/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/Parent.html#getRelativePath()

Comment: @ShriduttKothari Thanks, I looked at this option but I don't understand how to initialize the `RepositorySystem`, `MavenSession` and `ProjectBuilder`.

Comment: @khmarbaise My task is to build the parent hierarchical tree. And I think if I could get to the parent POM with Model.getParent() then with recursion I could achieve my goal. However, if there is another way to achieve this, then I do not mind.

Comment: `mvn dependency:tree` is much easier... (see maven-dependency-plugin https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) ...

Comment: @RomanDandali If you write your own Maven plugin, things like this are much easier than in plain Java.